# Error while calling another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm Calling MainMenu View as:

```
MainMenu *obj=[[MenuViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:obj animated:NO];
```

But it shows following error..

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "MenuViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Please Fix it.. thank you..

Comment: The error description itself mention what you have to do.Try to fix it yourself.

Comment: i did it.. thanks for -ve voating..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to open your nib in interface builder and connect your view with the view in File's Owner

Answer (score 1):

i think your problem clearly in the error try to catch that error

```
loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "MenuViewController" nib.....>>> but the view outlet was not set
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your nib file and set your view outlet.